# Simplification of expressions containing radicals

Tags: algebra-precalculus, nested-radicals

As an example, consider the polynomial $f(x) = x^3 + x - 2 = (x - 1)(x^2 + x + 2)$ which clearly has a root $x = 1$.
But we can also find the roots using Cardano's method, which leads to

$$x = \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{28/27} + 1} - \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{28/27} - 1}$$

and two other roots.

It's easy to check numerically that this expression is really equal to $1$, but is there a way to derive it algebraically which isn't equivalent to showing that this expression satisfies $f(x) = 0$?

Comment: this is similar to my question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218027/find-the-possible-values-of-a-b-and-c

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/396915/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes.  The first thing to try is to guess that $\sqrt[3]{ \left( \sqrt{ \frac{28}{27} } \pm 1 \right) } = \pm \frac{1}{2} + \sqrt{a}$ for some $a$.  Cubing both sides then gives

$$\frac{2}{9} \sqrt{21} \pm 1 = \pm \frac{1}{8} + \frac{3}{4} \sqrt{a} \pm \frac{3}{2} a + a \sqrt{a}.$$

Setting $1 = \frac{1}{8} + \frac{3a}{2}$ gives $a = \frac{7}{12}$, and we can verify that

$$\frac{3}{4} \sqrt{a} + a \sqrt{a} = \frac{1}{8} \sqrt{21} + \frac{7}{72} \sqrt{21} = \frac{2}{9} \sqrt{21}$$

as desired.  If this method doesn't work then the problem becomes harder.

Comment: thanks, that was the kind of thing I was looking for.

Comment: Qiaochu, where does the $\pm 1/2$ in your guess come from?

Comment: It comes from the fact that we know the answer is 1.  If we didn't know the answer was 1 we'd have to solve a little Diophantine equation instead.

Answer (score 34):

There are very general algorithms known for radical denesting. Below is the structure theorem which lies at the foundation of these algorithms. It widely generalizes the heuristic employed by Qiaochu in his answer. It may be employed heuristically - in a similar manner as Qiaochu - to perform complicated denestings, without requiring much comprehension of the underlying theory.

In Bloemer's papers [FOCS '91](https://doi.org/10.1109/SFCS.1991.185434) &  [FOCS '92](https://doi.org/10.1109/SFCS.1992.267807) & [Algorithmica 2000](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s004530010028#citeas)  you will find polynomial-time algorithms for radical denesting. Informally, the key  Denesting Structure Theorem says that if a radical $\:\! r^{1/d}\:\!$ denests in any radical extension $\:\! F' \:\!$ of its base field $\:\! F \:\!,\,$ then a suitable multiple $\:\! qb\, r \,$ of
the radicand $\:\!r\:\!$ must already denest in the field $\, F' \,$ defined by the
radicand. More precisely

**Denesting Structure Theorem for Real Fields** $\ $  Let $\, F \,$ be a real field and $\, F' = F(q_1^{1/d1},\ldots,q_k^{1/dk}) \,$ be a real radical extension of $\, F \,$ of degree $\, n. \,$ By $\, B = \{b_0,\ldots, b_{n-1}\}$ denote the standard basis of $\:\! F' $ over $\, F. \,$ If $\, r \,$ is in $\:\! F'$ and $\, d \,$ is a positive integer such
that $\, r^{1/d} \,$ denests over $\:\! F \:\!$ using only real radicals, that is
$\, r^{1/d} \in F(a_1^{1/t_1},\ldots,a_m^{1/t_m}) \,$ for positive integers
$\, t_i \,$ and positive $\, a_i \in F,\,$ then there exists a nonzero $\, q \in F \,$ and  $\, b \in B \,$ with $\, (q b r)^{1/d} \in F'.$

I.e. scaling the radicand by some $\:\! q \:\!$ in the base field $\, F \,$
and a power product $\,\! b = q_1^{e_1/d_1}\cdots q_k^{e_k/d_k} \,$ we can
normalize any denesting so that it denests in the field defined
by the radicand. E.g.

$$ \sqrt{\sqrt[3]5 - \sqrt[3]4} \,\,=\, \frac{1}3 (\sqrt[3]2 + \sqrt[3]{20} - \sqrt[3]{25})$$
normalises to $$\qquad \sqrt{18\ (\sqrt[3]10 - 2)} \,\,=\, 2 + 2\ \sqrt[3]{10} - \sqrt[3]{10}^2\,\in\,\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{10}) $$

An example with nontrivial $\,b$

$$  \sqrt{12 + 5\ \sqrt 6} \,\,=\, (\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3)\ 6^{1/4}\qquad\quad $$

normalises to

$$ \sqrt{\frac{1}3 \sqrt{6}\, (12 + 5\ \sqrt 6)} \,\,=\, 2 + \sqrt{6}\,\in\, \Bbb Q(\sqrt 6)\qquad\qquad\ \ \  $$

Here $\, F=\mathbb Q,\ F' = \mathbb Q(\sqrt 6),\ n=2,\ B = \{1,\sqrt 6\},\ d=2,\ q=1/3,\ b= \sqrt 6\,$.

The structure theorem also holds for complex fields except in this case one has to assume that $\, F \,$ contains enough roots of
unity (which may prove computationally expensive in practice, to
wit doubly-exponential complexity).

Note that the complexity of even simpler problems involving
radicals is currently unknown. For example, no polynomial time
algorithm is known for determining the sign of a sum of real
radicals $\, \sum{c_i\, q_i^{1/r_i}} \,$ where $\, c_i,\, q_i \,$ are rational numbers and
$\, r_i \,$ is a positive integer. Such sums play an important role in
various geometric problems (e.g. Euclidean shortest paths and
traveling salesman tours). Even though testing whether such a sum
of radicals is zero can be decided in polynomial time, this is
of no help in determining the sign, it only shows that if sign
testing is in $\, NP \,$ then it is already in $\, NP \cap \text{co-NP} \,$.

Comment: nice answer, thanks Bill. Are the denesting algorithms implemented in any CAS? Maxima didn't seem to be able to do it for example.

Comment: Macsyma (and more weakly Maxima) have only some less powerful heuristics (mainly due to Gosper). I had hoped to implement some of my work and Bloemer's but, alas, never found the spare time. I don't know the current status for other CAS.

Comment: I could verify that Maple doesn't automatically equates the example expression to 1, but applying its `simplify` function to it yields 1

Answer (score 17):

Pardon my skepticism, but has anyone so much as breadboarded Blömer '92 or Landau '93 in all these 18 years?  For lack of same, people still publish ugly surdballs, *e.g.*,
$$\vartheta _3\left(0,e^{-6 \pi }\right)=\frac{\sqrt[3]{-4+3 \sqrt{2}+3 \sqrt[4]{3}+2 \sqrt{3}-3^{3/4}+2 \sqrt{2}\, 3^{3/4}} \sqrt[4]{\pi }}{2\
   3^{3/8} \sqrt[6]{\left(\sqrt{2}-1\right) \left(\sqrt{3}-1\right)} \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}$$
(J. Yi / J. Math. Anal. Appl. 292 (2004) 381–400, Thm 5.5 vi) instead of
$$\vartheta _3\left(0,e^{-6 \pi }\right)=\frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2} \sqrt[4]{3}+\sqrt{6}} \,\sqrt[4]{\pi }}{2\ 3^{3/8} \Gamma
   \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}\quad .$$
And why do both papers trot out the same old Ramanujan denestings instead of new and interesting ones?  *E.g.*,
$$\sqrt{2^{6/7}-1}=\frac{2^{8/7}-2^{6/7}+2^{5/7}+2^{3/7}-1}{\sqrt{7}}$$
or
$$\sqrt[3]{3^{3/5}-\sqrt[5]{2}}=\frac{2^{2/5}+\sqrt[5]{3}+2^{3/5} 3^{2/5}-\sqrt[5]{2}\, 3^{3/5}}{5^{2/3}}$$
or
$$\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}\, 3^{3/4}}}{\sqrt[6]{\sqrt{3}-1}}=\frac{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2} \sqrt[4]{3}}}{\sqrt[6]{2}}\quad ?$$
These results were found by two young students of mine who would very much like to know values of *q* and *b* in Bill Dubuque's structure theorem which effect the denesting
$$\sqrt[3]{-\frac{106}{25}-\frac{369 \sqrt{3}}{125}+\frac{3 \sqrt{3} \left(388+268 \sqrt{3}\right)}{100 \sqrt[3]{2}\,
   5^{2/3}}}=\frac{3}{5^{2/3}}-\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt[3]{10}}+\frac{1}{5} \sqrt[3]{2} \left(3+2 \sqrt{3}\right)\quad.$$
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know what's been done since Blömer's work since I haven't kept up on this line of research. His results are described in full detail in his publications. If memory serves correct, there is still much work to be done to obtain *efficient* algorithms. Note: I found your post only now by accident. This software platform notifies users only if you answer their question, comment on their answer, or write @username in a comment thread they are in. Of course you can always reach me at my first.lastname at gmail.

Comment: "breadboarded"?

Comment: I'm guessing "breadboarded" is in the EE-sense of implementing a prototype. I too have been looking for confirmed implementations of either Landau's or Blömer's algorithm in some CAS... and found nothing! There's 1999 paper by some Maple guys ("Simplifying Square Roots of Square Roots by Denesting" in a CAS volume edited by Michael J. Wester) which says something along the lines that heuristics are more practical. A recent book, *A Classical Introduction to Galois Theory* by Stephen C. Newman only mentions Zippel denesting.