# Simplify $\sqrt {\sqrt[3]{5}-\sqrt[3]{4}}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, nested-radicals

> Denest $\sqrt {\sqrt[3]{5}-\sqrt[3]{4}}$.

I have tried completing square by several method but all failed. Can anyone help me please? Thank you.

p.s. I'm a poor question-tagger.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This example is discussed in one of my [prior posts,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4697/242) based on a polynomial-time denesting algorithm of Blomer. Using standard Galois theory of radical (Kummer) extensions, it is not difficult to prove a  *Denesting Structure Theorem*, which implies that if a radical $\, r^{1/d} \,$ denests in any radical extension $\, F'$ of its base field $\, F$, then a suitable multiple $\, q b\, r \,$ of the radicand $\, r \,$ must already denest in the field $\, F' $ defined by the radicand. More precisely

**Denesting Structure Theorem for Real Fields** $\ $  Let $\, F \,$ be a real field and $\, F' = F(q_1^{1/d1},\ldots,q_k^{1/dk}) \,$ be a real radical extension of $\, F \,$ of degree $\, n. \,$ By $\, B = \{b_0,\ldots, b_{n-1}\}$ denote the standard basis of $\, F' \,$ over $\, F. \,$ If $\, r \,$ is in $\, F'$ and $\, d \,$ is a positive integer such
that $\, r^{1/d} \,$ denests over $\, F \,$ using only real radicals, that is
$\, r^{1/d} \in F(a_1^{1/t_1},\ldots,a_m^{1/t_m}) \,$ for positive integers
$\, t_i \,$ and positive $\, a_i \in F,\,$ then there exists a nonzero $\, q \in F \,$ and  $\, b \in B \,$ with $\, (q b r)^{1/d} \in F'.$

This implies that by multiplying the radicand by a $\, q \,$ in the base field $\, F \,$
and a power product $\, b \,=\, q_1^{e_1/d_1}\cdots q_k^{e_k/d_k} \,$ we can
*normalize* any denesting so that it denests in the field defined
by the radicand (then denesting reduces to solving for undetermined coefficients). For example

$$ \sqrt{\sqrt[3]5 - \sqrt[3]4} \,\,=\, \frac{1}3 (\sqrt[3]2 + \sqrt[3]{20} - \sqrt[3]{25})$$
normalises to $$ \sqrt{18\ (\sqrt[3]10 - 2)} \,\,=\, 2 + 2\ \sqrt[3]{10} - \sqrt[3]{10}^2 $$

An example with nontrivial $\,b$

$$  \sqrt{12 + 5\ \sqrt 6} \,\,=\, (\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3)\ 6^{1/4} $$

normalises to

$$ \sqrt{\frac{1}3 \sqrt{6}\, (12 + 5\ \sqrt 6)} \,\,=\, 2 + \sqrt{6} $$

Here $\, F=\mathbb Q,\ F' = \mathbb Q(\sqrt 6),\ n=2,\ B = \{1,\sqrt 6\},\ d=2,\ q=1/3,\ b= \sqrt 6\,$.

The structure theorem also holds for complex fields except that
we must assume that $\, F \,$ contains enough roots of
unity (which may be computationally expensive in practice, to
wit doubly-exponential complexity).

Comment: The "algorithm of Blomer" being, presumably, discussed in the link in my answer.

Comment: @Gerry I think that paper is one of the references I cited in my answer here two years ago (based on one of my old sci.math posts).

Comment: Is it perhaps a little tough to quote Galois theory of radical (Kummer) extensions when assisting someone struggling with an algebra-precalculus question?

Comment: @JohnSenior Please note that you don't need to understand any Galois theory to use the method in simple cases like this. It's analogous to the Risch structure theorem for integration in finite terms. Once you know the structure of the answer, finding the undetermined coefficients is simple algebra. There are no simpler approaches that work generally.

Comment: That is true, but I was just empathising with an original poster being faced with an answer which is clearly at a much greater level of sophistication than the question.

Comment: @JohnSenior It occurs quite frequently in mathematics that elementary problems require nonelementary techniques for their solution. Here one might get lucky and correctly guess the structure of the answer. But mathematics is not based on pulling rabbits out of hats. When there are general methods that can be explained at an elementary level, we should strive to do so.

Answer (score 8):

See Johannes Blomer, How to denest Ramanujan's nested radicals, available [here](http://pdf.aminer.org/001/059/825/simplification_of_nested_radicals.pdf).

Answer (score 5):

There is a formula. I'm not too sure how to prove it, but I know that there is a formula where you can denest $$\sqrt{\sqrt[3]{\alpha}+\sqrt[3]{\beta}}$$Into$$\pm\frac {1}{\sqrt{f}}\left(-\frac {s^2\sqrt[3]{\alpha^2}}{2}+s\sqrt[3]{\alpha\beta}+\sqrt[3]{\beta^2}\right)$$ where $$f=\beta-s^3\alpha$$ and $s$ is a real number solution to $f(x)=x^4+4x^3+8\frac {\beta}{\alpha}x-4\frac {\beta}{\alpha}$

So in this case, $\alpha=5$ and $\beta=-4$. So $s=-2$ and $f=-4-(-2)^3\times 5=36$ Therefore, we have$$\pm\frac {1}{6}\left(-\frac {4\sqrt[3]{25}}{2}-2\sqrt[3]{-20}+\sqrt[3]{16}\right)=\pm\frac {1}{3}\left(-\sqrt[3]{25}+\sqrt[3]{20}+\sqrt[3]{2}\right)$$

Discard the negative value to get $\sqrt{\sqrt[3]{5}-\sqrt[3]{4}}=\frac {1}{3}\left(-\sqrt[3]{25}+\sqrt[3]{20}+\sqrt[3]{2}\right)$

Comment: Any online source for this?

Comment: @PragyadityaDas I believe that there's a pdf document explaining the proof and steps.

Comment: @Crescendo can you provide me with the link?

Comment: See https://repository.ubn.ru.nl/bitstream/handle/2066/18722/18722.pdf?sequence=1.

Answer (score 1):

I will give you a hint. Seek denesting which looks like this :
$$ (\sqrt[3]{a} + \sqrt[3]{b} - \sqrt[3]{c})^2 = 9(\sqrt[3]{5}-\sqrt[3]{4}) $$

Comment: How do you get that $\sqrt[3]{a}+\sqrt[3]{b}-\sqrt[3]{c}$? +_+