# Square root of surds: $\sqrt{12+2\sqrt{6}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, radicals, nested-radicals

I got this question

> Find the square root of $12+2\sqrt{6}$ expressing your answer in the form $\sqrt{m}+\sqrt{n}$.

I have no idea what this means and how to go about it.

Comment: What is a surds?

Comment: @Euler....IS_ALIVE Are you serious with that question?

Comment: Irrational root in American English.

Comment: It was a serious question.  In 7 years of undergrad and graduate work, I've never seen that word.  I googled it, but I am fairly confident that is an unusual word.  Someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Euler....IS_ALIVE Quite usual, actually.

Comment: Oh, well I think that's quite absurd.  And go America!

Comment: @Euler....IS_ALIVE Well, since you know what I imply by surds, can you please tell me your own term for it?

Comment: @Mob Irrational numbers, probably. (Although that's a broader term.)

Comment: See also: [Denesting radicals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denesting_radicals) at Wikipedia, [Strategies to denest nested radicals](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/196155/strategies-to-denest-nested-radicals) (and the posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/196155)), [Denesting a square root: $\sqrt{7 + \sqrt{14}}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1214527/denesting-a-square-root-sqrt7-sqrt14) (and the posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/1214527))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $x = \sqrt{12 + 2\sqrt{6}} = \sqrt{n} + \sqrt{m}$. Then $x^2 = 12 + 2\sqrt 6 = n + m + 2 \sqrt{nm}$.

Find $n$ and $m$ such that $n + m = 12$ and $nm = 6$.

Comment: Can you expatiate on this?

Comment: Surdly you can solve the system of equations Damien has given.

Answer (score 1):

The answers for $n$ and $m$ are

$n = 6+\sqrt{30}$

$m = 6-\sqrt{30}$.

Notice that they are interchangable.