# How to compare numbers $\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{3}$ and $\sqrt{8-2\sqrt{15}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, nested-radicals

How to compare the following numbers without using the calculator? $\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{3}$ and $\sqrt{8-2\sqrt{15}}$

Comment: Is "radical(5)=$\;\sqrt5\;$ ?

Comment: See also: [Denesting radicals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denesting_radicals) at Wikipedia, [Strategies to denest nested radicals](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/196155/strategies-to-denest-nested-radicals) (and the posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/196155)).

Answer (score 3):

As $(\sqrt 5-\sqrt 3)^2=5+3-2\sqrt {15}$ they are equal

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\sqrt5-\sqrt3\ge\sqrt{8-2\sqrt{15}}\iff8-2\sqrt{15}\ge8-2\sqrt{15}\ldots$$