# Value of $\frac{\sqrt{10+\sqrt{1}}+\sqrt{10+\sqrt{2}}+\cdots+\sqrt{10+\sqrt{99}} }{\sqrt{10-\sqrt{1}}+\sqrt{10-\sqrt{2}}+\cdots+\sqrt{10-\sqrt{99}}}$

Tags: summation, radicals

Here is the question:

> $$\frac{\sqrt{10+\sqrt{1}}+\sqrt{10+\sqrt{2}}+\cdots+\sqrt{10+\sqrt{99}} }{\sqrt{10-\sqrt{1}}+\sqrt{10-\sqrt{2}}+\cdots+\sqrt{10-\sqrt{99}}} = \;?$$

([original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCHQ9.jpg))

I think we need to simplify it writing it in summation sign as you can see here:

$$\frac{\sum\limits_{n=1}^{99} \sqrt{10 + \sqrt{n}}}{\sum\limits_{n=1}^{99} \sqrt{10 - \sqrt{n}}}$$

or in Wolfram Alpha input in comments.

I can compute it too! It's easy to write a script for this kind of question.
I need a way to solve it. How would you solve it on a piece of paper?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Bsum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%7B99%7Dsqrt%2810%2Bsqrt%28n%29%29%5D%2F%5Bsum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%7B99%7Dsqrt%2810-sqrt%28n%29%29%5D

Comment: @DavidP: So is this a rational number???

Comment: highly unlikely http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2.41421-%5Bsum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%7B99%7Dsqrt%2810%2Bsqrt%28n%29%29%5D%2F%5Bsum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%7B99%7Dsqrt%2810-sqrt%28n%29%29%5D

Comment: @DavidP: Perhaps [this is still simple](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2Bsqrt(2)-%5Bsum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%7B99%7Dsqrt%2810%2Bsqrt%28n%29%29%5D%2F%5Bsum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%7B99%7Dsqrt%2810-sqrt%28n%29%29%5D)

Comment: @DavidP That's actually $\sqrt 2 + 1$

Comment: The ratio of the sums is an approximation of the ratio of integrals $\int_0^1\sqrt{1+\sqrt x} dx$ and $\int_0^1\sqrt{1-\sqrt x} dx$, which is $1+\sqrt 2$. The sum ratio is probably not $1+\sqrt{2}$

Comment: Can you add answers how you derived it?

Comment: @Henry wolfram's precision is great around 10^{-6}

Comment: It looks as if $\dfrac{\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{k^2-1} \sqrt{k + \sqrt{n}}}{\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{k^2-1} \sqrt{k - \sqrt{n}}} = \sqrt{2}+1$ for integer $k\gt 1$

Comment: Any idea why we get √2 + 1 in this type of ratios? @Henry

Answer (score 20):

Hint: Show that for all relevant $n$
$$
\frac{\sqrt{10+\sqrt{100-n}}+\sqrt{10+\sqrt{n}}}{\sqrt{10-\sqrt{100-n}}+
\sqrt{10-\sqrt{n}}}=\sqrt2 +1.
$$
IOW pair up terms in the numerator and the denominator starting from both ends.

---

[Edit:]

**Claim.** Assume that $a,b,c$, all positive, are the lengths of the sides of a right angled triangle - a Pythagorean triple if you like - $c$ is the hypotenuse. Then
$$
\frac{\sqrt{c+a}+\sqrt{c+b}}{\sqrt{c-a}+\sqrt{c-b}}=1+\sqrt2.
$$

**Proof.** The left hand side of the claim is clearly immune to scaling. We can adjust the scale so that $c-b=2$. Then a calculation (familiar to enthusiasts of Pythagorean triples) shows that for some positive real number $m$ we have
$$c=m^2+1,\quad b=m^2-1,\quad a=2m.$$ (IOW instead of the usual integer parametrization in terms of $(m,n)$ we set $n=1$, and let $m$ be arbitrary.) We then see that the numerator is $m+1+\sqrt2 m=m(1+\sqrt2)+1$, and the denominator is $m-1+\sqrt2$. Because $(\sqrt2+1)^{-1}=\sqrt2-1$ the claim follows. Q.E.D.

Leaving it to the reader to derive the identity of my hint as a corollary of the claim.

Comment: It goes too hairy to show that ratio. Is there any other way around?

Comment: Not sure about the best way. One way is to use a trigonometric substitution $n=100\sin^2x$ and work with half-angle formulas. That's how I verified it. The ratio I wrote simplifies to 
$$\frac{\cos t+\cos(\pi/4-t)}{\sin t+\sin(\pi/4-t)}=1+\sqrt2$$ for $t=x/2$ Admittedly that feels like hiding the key point. :-( The appearance of the formulas somehow suggested trig substitution for me. May be a geometric justification is better?!

Comment: Actually this ratio known as Silver Ratio, as you know. Therefore as you say, a geometric representation can be helpful. I'll give it a try. If you get something helpful please comment here. Thank you :)

Comment: I do not know how to go from your hint the the solution of the problem. What is amazing is that the derivative of your expression with respect to $n$ is strictly $0$ (tedious calculation). So, the rhs can be computed for $n=0$ to get the result !.

Comment: @Claude: You may have guessed that I also plotted the l.h.s. to be sure :-) Once we have verified that this ratio is a constant, then we can pair up the terms in the numerator, and replace them with $(1+\sqrt2)$ times the corresponding pair in the denominator. After having done this for all the pairs (the odd term in the middle, $n=50$, needs to be halved and paired up with itself) the denominator goes Poof!

Comment: Summary of how I feel. My "big" contribution was to observe that we should pair up the terms like here. I am leaving the search for the best way of proving constancy of this ratio for others. It's the last weekend of my vacation, and I want to go to the forest and forage a bucketload of blueberries (and fight mosquitoes and flies). <Homer Simpson voice> Mmmm...Blueberry pie. </Homer Simpson voice>

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen +1 just for priorities. :)

Comment: The claim can also be proved using JuanTheron's trick (+1) of squaring the difference of two relevant square roots.

Comment: Very instructive! (+1)

Answer (score 16):

For the Calculation of  $$\displaystyle \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n^2-1}\sqrt{n+\sqrt{k}}}{\sum_{k=1}^{n^2-1}\sqrt{n-\sqrt{k}}} = $$

Let $$\displaystyle A_{n} = \sum_{k=1}^{n^2-1}\sqrt{n+\sqrt{k}}$$ and $$\displaystyle B_{n} = \sum_{k=1}^{n^2-1}\sqrt{n-\sqrt{k}}$$ , where $n>1$

Now $$\left(\sqrt{n+\sqrt{k}}-\sqrt{n-\sqrt{k}}\right)^2 = 2n-2\sqrt{n^2-k}$$

So $$\left(\sqrt{n+\sqrt{k}}-\sqrt{n-\sqrt{k}}\right) = \sqrt{2}\cdot \sqrt{n-\sqrt{n^2-k}}$$

So $$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n^2-1}\left(\sqrt{n+\sqrt{k}}-\sqrt{n-\sqrt{k}}\right) = \sum_{k=1}^{n^2-1}\sqrt{2}\cdot \sqrt{n-\sqrt{n^2-k}}$$

So So $$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n^2-1}\left(\sqrt{n+\sqrt{k}}-\sqrt{n-\sqrt{k}}\right) = \sum_{k=1}^{n^2-1}\sqrt{2}\cdot \sqrt{n-\sqrt{k}}$$

So $$A_{n}-B_{n} = B_{n}\sqrt{2}$$

So $$A_{n} = B_{n}\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)$$

So $$\displaystyle \frac{A_{n}}{B_{n}} = 1+\sqrt{2}$$

Now Put $\displaystyle n^2-1 = 99\Rightarrow n= 10\;,$ So we get $$\displaystyle \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{99}\sqrt{n+\sqrt{k}}}{\sum_{k=1}^{99}\sqrt{n-\sqrt{k}}} =\frac{A_{10}}{B_{10}} = 1+\sqrt{2}.$$

Comment: Very nice and clever! (+1)

Comment: This is nice. Note that it is not necessary to have a perfect square minus one as the maximum. The same arguments show that e.g.$$
\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{2016}+\sqrt{1}}+\sqrt{\sqrt{2016}+\sqrt{2}}+\cdots+\sqrt{\sqrt{2016}+\sqrt{2015}}}
{\sqrt{\sqrt{2016}-\sqrt{1}}+\sqrt{\sqrt{2016}-\sqrt{2}}+\cdots+\sqrt{\sqrt{2016}-\sqrt{2015}}}=1+\sqrt2.
$$

Comment: Yes  Jyrki Lahtonen You are Right,

Answer (score 13):

Let $f(n)=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sqrt{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{k}}}{\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sqrt{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{k}}}$, and the original problem is to calculate $f(99)$.

Now we claim that $f(n)=\sqrt{2}+1$ for $\forall n>0$.

$f(n)=\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{2}+1}}{\sqrt{\sqrt{2}-1}} \cdot \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sqrt{(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{k})(\sqrt{2}-1)}}{\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sqrt{(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{k})(\sqrt{2}+1)}}$

$=(\sqrt{2}+1) \cdot \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sqrt{A(k)+B(k)}}{\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sqrt{A(k)-B(k)}}$, where $A(k)=\sqrt{2(n+1)}-\sqrt{k}$, $B(k)=\sqrt{2k}-\sqrt{n+1}$.

Notice that:

$\left(\sqrt{A(k)+B(k)}-\sqrt{A(k)-B(k)}\right)^2=2A(k)-2\sqrt{A(k)^2-B(k)^2}\\=2\left(\sqrt{2(n+1)}-\sqrt{k}-\sqrt{n+1-k}\right)$

That means

$\left(\sqrt{A(n+1-k)+B(n+1-k)}-\sqrt{A(n+1-k)-B(n+1-k)}\right)^2\\=2\left(\sqrt{2(n+1)}-\sqrt{n+1-k}-\sqrt{k}\right)$

So that

$\sqrt{A(k)+B(k)}-\sqrt{A(k)-B(k)}\\=\sqrt{A(n+1-k)-B(n+1-k)}-\sqrt{A(n+1-k)+B(n+1-k)}$

So that

$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sqrt{A(k)+B(k)}=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sqrt{A(k)-B(k)}$

So that $f(n)=\boxed{\sqrt{2}+1}$

Comment: No problems! Thanks for trying to correct me

Comment: This answer deserves more upvotes.  It doesn't seem like people realize you've proved a more general theorem than the others, because $n$ needn't be a square.

Comment: Thanks for the consideration!

Comment: If I did it with a colleague, it's not just mine

Answer (score 12):

The hint
$$
\frac{ \sqrt{1+\sin(x)}+\sqrt{1+\cos(x)} }{ \sqrt{1-\sin(x)}+\sqrt{1-\cos(x)} }=1+\sqrt2 \quad \text{for } x\in [0,\pi/2]
$$
is spot on.

We have
$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt{10+\sqrt{1}}+\sqrt{10+\sqrt{99}}
&=
\sqrt{10}\left(\sqrt{1+\sqrt{0.01}}+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{0.99}}\right)
\\&=
\sqrt{10}\left(\sqrt{1+\sin(t)}+\sqrt{1+\cos(t)}\right)
\\&=
\sqrt{10}(1+\sqrt 2)\left(\sqrt{1-\sin(t)}+\sqrt{1-\cos(t)}\right)
\\&=
\sqrt{10}(1+\sqrt 2)\left(\sqrt{1-\sqrt{0.01}}+\sqrt{1-\sqrt{0.99}}\right)
\\&=
(1+\sqrt 2)\left(\sqrt{10-\sqrt{1}}+\sqrt{10-\sqrt{99}}\right)
\end{align}
$$
for some $t$.
Therefore, we can rearrange the numerator to be $1+\sqrt 2$ times the denominator. (You need to handle the middle terms separately but it works out the same.)

Comment: Interesting (+1). I assume you can generalize this to $$\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{m^2-1}\sqrt{m+\sqrt{n}}}{\sum_{n=1}^{m^2-1}\sqrt{m-\sqrt{n}}}=1+\sqrt{2}?$$

Comment: @clathratus, yes, it seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: In the middle (whiche happens in general for even $m$), you need one case where you do not pair two summands, but of course $\frac{\sqrt{10+\sqrt{50}}}{\sqrt{10-\sqrt{50}}}=1+\sqrt 2$ as well.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, yes, of course. Thanks for point it out.

Answer (score 11):

Let the numerator and the denominator

$$N= \sqrt{10+\sqrt{1}}+\sqrt{10+\sqrt{2}}+\ldots+\sqrt{10+\sqrt{99}}$$
$$D =\sqrt{10-\sqrt{1}}+\sqrt{10-\sqrt{2}}+\ldots+\sqrt{10-\sqrt{99}}$$

Apply the denesting formulas

$$\sqrt{a\pm\sqrt c} = \frac{1}{\sqrt2} \left( \sqrt{a+\sqrt{a^2-c}} \pm 
\sqrt{a-\sqrt{a^2-c}} \right)$$

to get

$$\sqrt{10\pm\sqrt n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt2} \left( \sqrt{10+\sqrt{100-n}} \pm 
\sqrt{10-\sqrt{100-n}} \right)$$

where $n=1,2,...99$. As a result,

$$N= \frac{1}{\sqrt2}(N+D), \>\>\>\>\>D= \frac{1}{\sqrt2}(N-D)$$
Take the ratio,

$$\frac ND=\frac{N+D}{N-D}$$

or,

$$\left(\frac ND\right)^2 - 2\frac ND -1 =0$$

Solve to obtain,

$$\frac ND = 1+\sqrt2$$

Comment: Nice solution (+1). Where did you find those denesting formulas?

Comment: @Axion004 - It is not hard to derive it, or see the link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_radical

Answer (score 10):

Rewrite the sum as
$$\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{99} \sqrt{10+\sqrt{n}}}{\sum_{n=1}^{99} \sqrt{10-\sqrt{n}}} = \frac{a}{b}$$
then let
$$\Delta_n = \sqrt{10+\sqrt{n}} - \sqrt{10-\sqrt{n}}$$
By squaring $\Delta_n$ and simplifying we get
$$\Delta_n = \sqrt{2} \sqrt{10 - \sqrt{100-n}}$$
Now summing all those $\Delta_n$s can be done by letting the index $n$ run from $1$ to $99$ and replacing $\sqrt{100-n}$ with $\sqrt{n}$ since both cases will yield the same summands. Hence
$$\sum_{n=1}^{99} \Delta_n = \sqrt{2} \sum_{n=1}^{99}\sqrt{10 - \sqrt{n}} = \sqrt{2} \cdot b$$
thus
$$\frac{a-b}{b} = \frac{a}{b} - 1 = \sqrt{2} \implies \frac{a}{b} = \sqrt{2} + 1$$

Comment: Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to add one more answer "by color-coding".
First, observe that
$$
\sqrt{n+\sqrt{k}}-\sqrt{n-\sqrt{k}} = \sqrt{2}\sqrt{n-\sqrt{n^2-k}}.
$$
Now the problem.
Designate
$$
x = \frac{\sqrt{10+\sqrt{1}}+\sqrt{10+\sqrt{2}}+\cdots+\sqrt{10+\sqrt{99}} }{\sqrt{10-\sqrt{1}}+\sqrt{10-\sqrt{2}}+\cdots+\sqrt{10-\sqrt{99}}},
$$
and calculate
$$
x-1 =
\frac{\overbrace{\sqrt{10+\sqrt{1}}-\sqrt{10-\sqrt{1}}}^{\color{red}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{10-\sqrt{99}}}} 
+ \cdots + 
\overbrace{\sqrt{10+\sqrt{99}}-\sqrt{10-\sqrt{99}}}^{\color{blue}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{10-\sqrt{1}}}} }{\color{blue}{\sqrt{10-\sqrt{1}}}+\cdots+\color{red}{\sqrt{10-\sqrt{99}}}}.
$$
Everything simplifies to $\sqrt{2}$, thus
$$
x = 1 + \sqrt{2}
$$

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen  Yes, you are perfectly right. I did a typo due to copy-paste. Many thanks!