# Simplify: $\frac{\sqrt{10+\sqrt{1}}+\sqrt{10+\sqrt{2}}+\ldots+\sqrt{10+\sqrt{99}}}{\sqrt{10-\sqrt{1}}+\sqrt{10-\sqrt{2}}+\ldots+\sqrt{10-\sqrt{99}}}$

Tags: trigonometry, summation, radicals

$\frac{ \sqrt{1+\sin(x)}+\sqrt{1+\cos(x)} }{ \sqrt{1-\sin(x)}+\sqrt{1-\cos(x)} }=\sqrt2+1\,\forall x\in [0,\pi/2]$
the fraction of square roots may be simplified using double angle formulas.. though i wouldn't recommend showing the derivative to be 0...

Comment: This question is a [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1397863/value-of-frac-sqrt10-sqrt1-sqrt10-sqrt2-cdots-sqrt10-sqrt99).