# Simplify $\sqrt{1+\sqrt 2}$

Tags: complex-numbers, radicals, nested-radicals

When I was computing $\sqrt{1+i}$, $\sqrt{1+\sqrt 2}$ came up and I could not simplify it. So the question is how to simplify $\sqrt{1+\sqrt 2}$, or is it in the most simplified form?

Comment: I don't see any way to simplify it.

Comment: What do you mean by simplify? In which sense is it not simple?

Comment: @IttayWeiss I just mean I don't want to see a square root inside another square root. Is there a more universal definition of simplified form?

Comment: See also: [Denesting radicals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denesting_radicals) at Wikipedia, [Strategies to denest nested radicals](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/196155/strategies-to-denest-nested-radicals) (and the posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/196155)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your aim is to rewrite $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}$ as a linear combination (with rational coefficients) of square roots of integers, it's not possible.

In some cases you can do it, for instance
$$
\sqrt{8+4\sqrt{3}}=\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}
$$
which you can check by squaring both sides. In the case of $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}$ you can't find such an expression.

Suppose $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}=p\sqrt{a}+q\sqrt{b}$, with $a,b,p,q$ rational. Then, after squaring,
$$
1+\sqrt{2}=ap^2+bq^2+2pq\sqrt{ab}
$$
You can easily prove that this implies
$$
\begin{cases}
ap^2+bq^2=1 \\[4px]
2pq\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{2}
\end{cases}
$$
and the second equation implies $2abp^2q^2=1$. Set $x=ap^2$ and $y=bq^2$, so $x+y=1$ and $2xy=1$. In particular, $x$ and $y$ are the roots of
$$
t^2-t+\frac{1}{2}=0
$$
which has negative discriminant, so no rational solutions.

Comment: Is $p\sqrt a+q\sqrt b$ of the most general form? Why is $p\sqrt a+q\sqrt b+r\sqrt c$ not possible?

Comment: @ZiruiWang I wanted to keep it simple. With advanced tools it can be shown that also your more general form isn't possible.

Comment: @egreg: What are the advanced tools you have in mind?

Comment: @user21820 Tools from Galois theory.

Comment: @egreg: I know that, but what is the easiest method you have in mind? $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}$ is in a quartic extension of the rationals, but it is also possible for $p\sqrt{a}+q\sqrt{b}+r\sqrt{c}$ to be, despite $a,b,c$ being square-free and distinct, just that that would mean $abc$ is a square.

Answer (score 1):

Radical unnesting would be done with

$$\sqrt{1+\sqrt2}=a\sqrt2+b$$

or

$$1+\sqrt2=2a^2+b^2+2\sqrt2ab.$$

By identification,

$$2a^2+b^2=1,2ab=1.$$

Then

$$2a^4+a^2b^2=a^2,\\
2a^4-a^2+\frac14=0,$$

which doesn't have real solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If it were possible to simplify it, one might expect it to be written as $$a+b\sqrt{2}$$ where $a$ and $b$ are rational. This is like when you simplify $$\sqrt{4+2\sqrt{3}}=1+\sqrt{3}$$ for example.

However is you set $$(a+b\sqrt{2})^2=1+\sqrt{2}$$

you will get, by comparing rational and irrational parts, a pair of equations $$a^2+2b^2=1$$ and $$2ab=1$$

These equations have no real solution for $a$ and $b$, so you already have the simplest form.