# How can the surd $\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}$ be expressed?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, nested-radicals

I was wondering how $\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}$ could be expressed in terms of $\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{2}}$.
I did try to solve both the expressions separately but none of them seemed to match. 
I would appreciate it if someone could also mention the procedure

Comment: Since $$\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2=\frac{3-2\sqrt{3}+1}{2}=2-\sqrt{3}\qquad\text{and}\qquad 2-\sqrt{3}>0$$
It follows that $$\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}=\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Comment: You mean $\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{2}}>0$?

Comment: i was wondering whether we could do it the other way round i.e $\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}$ = $\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{2}}$.                                                                            Could you mention the procedure aswell.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/196155/strategies-to-denest-nested-radicals

Comment: Here is the [MathJax guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Theorem:** Given a nested radical of the form $\sqrt{X\pm Y}$, it can be rewritten into the form $$\sqrt{\frac {X+\sqrt{X^2-Y^2}}{2}}\pm\sqrt{\frac {X-\sqrt{X^2-Y^2}}{2}}\tag{1}$$
Where $X>Y$.

---

Therefore, we have $X=2,Y=\sqrt{3}$ because $2>\sqrt{3}$. So plugging that into $(1)$ gives us $$\sqrt{\frac {2+\sqrt{4-3}}{2}}-\sqrt{\frac {2-\sqrt{4-3}}{2}}\tag{2}$$
Simplifying $(2)$ gives us $$\sqrt{\frac {2+1}{2}}-\sqrt{\frac {2-1}{2}}\implies \sqrt{\frac 32}-\sqrt{\frac 12}$$

$$\therefore\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}=\frac {\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

---

Alternatively, one can rewrite it as a sum of two surds, and simplify from there. Specifically, let $\sqrt{2-\sqrt3}$ equal $\sqrt d-\sqrt e$. Squaring, we get\begin{align*} & 2-\sqrt3=d+e-2\sqrt{de}\\ & \therefore\begin{cases}d+e=2\\de=\frac 34\end{cases}\end{align*}
With solving for $d$ and $e$ gives the simplification.

Comment: when you solve for d and e though, you get 1.5 and 0.5. When you sub this into the equation aren't you then saying that $\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}=\sqrt{1.5} + \sqrt{0.5}$? How do you get around this?

Comment: @frog1944 Oh wait, there's a sign change that I added wrong... Anyways, it's now fixed.

Comment: ok, thank you very much. It makes more sense now