# simplify 2$\sqrt{3+\sqrt{5-\sqrt{13+\sqrt{48}}}}$

Tags: radicals, nested-radicals

Simplify the following expression:

2$\sqrt{3+\sqrt{5-\sqrt{13+\sqrt{48}}}}$

I would be grateful to get a full response.

Comment: You might get some good ideas here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/196155/strategies-to-denest-nested-radicals

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $13+4\sqrt{3}=(1+2\sqrt{3})^2$ and $4-2\sqrt{3}=(\sqrt{3}-1)^2$, your surd is$$2\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}=\sqrt{8+2\sqrt{12}}=\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6}.$$

Answer (score 4):

Hint

$$13+\sqrt{48}=12+1+2\sqrt{12}=(\sqrt{12}+1)^2$$

Alternatively

We need $$a^2+b^2=13,a^2b^2=12$$ where $a,b>0$

So, $a^2,b^2$ are the roots of $$t^2-13t+12=0$$