# How to simplify these complex expressions?

Tags: complex-numbers

I have expressions:

$F(s)=\sqrt{\left[\left(a+b\right)s+c\right]\mp\sqrt{\left[\left(a-b\right)s+c\right]^{2}+d}}$

where $s$ is a complex number; and $a,b,c,d$ are reals such that

$a>0,\,b>0,\, a\neq b,\, c>0,\, d\geq0$. I am trying to figure out
whether

it is possible to simplify these expressions when $d=0$,

but I am afraid I have forgotten how to deal with the

constructs of the type $\sqrt{z^{2}}$ for the complex $z$ arising
here.

Can anybody help me please?

Leszek

Clarification 1:

I may be terribly uneducated, but what else can $\sqrt{z}$ mean, if not
"the square root of $z$"?

I never assume that the expressions of which the square roots are taken
are integers. Please read my description above.

I think my problem can be expressed in a simpler way: what is the result
of calculating $\sqrt{z^{2}}$ when $z$ is complex, and how this result depends on the actual form of $z$, as is described?

When $z$ is real, then $\sqrt{z^{2}}$ is equal to the absolute value of $z$.
Obviously I expect this is not the case when $z$ is complex.

Assuming a special case of real $s$  and $a > b$, we would obtain simplified expressions:

$F(s)=\sqrt{2bs}$ when there is "-" in the formula for $F(s)$,

and
$F(s)=\sqrt{2as+2c}$ when there is "+" in the formula for $F(s)$

I need to derive the counterparts of such simplified expressions obtainable for complex  $s$, both when $a > b$ and when $a < b$.

Leszek

Comment: What does $\sqrt z$ mean? (And, please, don't answer “the square root of $z$”.)

Comment: Do you need a general algebraic form, or is what you are stating simply a generalization of a specific numerical expression? Note that for integers $m$ and $n,$ it is not possible in general to express $\sqrt{m + \sqrt n}$ using integers and a single radical symbol, but [for certain special cases it is possible](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/196155/13130). It might also be helpful to know what you need the simplification for, since it might actually be unnecessary for what you want to do.

Comment: I have added Clarification 1

Comment: The complex square root isn't well-defined so whatever it is you mean by $\sqrt{z}$ need to be explained. It's not normally a meaningful expression.

Answer (score -1):

The function square root $\sqrt{z}$ is defined on the complex plane minus a curve connecting the points $z = 0$ and $z =\infty$. The curve is usually taken as the positive or negative half-axis of the real line. Therefore, the result $\sqrt{z^2}$ depends on the chosen branch. Moreovere, if you take a point on the curve, be careful which side of the curve cointains this point.

A simplification can be implemented, for instance, in Mathematica by a description of the fixed branch. Maybe the following example in Mathematica will clarify the role of the branch definition:

```
In[1]:= f[z_] = Sqrt[z^2 - 1] - Sqrt[z + 1] Sqrt[z - 1];
        f[I - 1.] // Simplify
Out[2]= 1.5723 - 2.54404 I
```