# What are some obscure radical identities?

Tags: functions, radicals, radical-equations

So there are several trigonometric identities, some very well know, such as $\cos(x) = 1 - 2\sin^2(\frac{x}{2})$ and some more obscure like $\tan(\frac{\theta}{2} + \frac{\pi}{4}) = \sec(\theta)+\tan(\theta)$.

You can also find some logarithmic identities online

But looking for radical identities (stuff involving square roots), if I google I'm lead to politics and ethnicity (???)... I want to find some cool identities involving square roots that are always true for any $x>0$. I am aware they exist, I've seen some, but I don't remember them...

What are some cool obscure identities involving square roots?

Comment: Perhaps something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities?

Comment: You might look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/196155/strategies-to-denest-nested-radicals-sqrtab-sqrtc)

Comment: _surd_ would yield more relevant search results.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_radical (especially the identities due to Ramanujan)

Comment: In [this 5 December 1999 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/WMsswENsd50/m/6_fHZr_RI14J) I gave (with citations) some unusual radical identities that I had come across in a couple of 1907 papers by Salvatore Composto. Back then all I could do is post full bibliographic details and if anyone wanted to look them up (or verify that I wasn't making it all up), they'd have to visit a decent university library. **(continued)**

Comment: Now I can actually give google-books links -- [the *Peridico di Matematica* (3) 4 (1907), pp. 32-36 paper I cited](https://books.google.com/books?id=wVFaAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA32) and [the *Peridico di Matematica* (3) 4 (1907), pp. 75-83 paper I cited](https://books.google.com/books?id=wVFaAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA75).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro My goodness, sci.math links are still alive? I remember that forum with nostalgia. And whatever happened to James Harris and his so-called proof of FLT? 

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not so obscure, but: [with thanks to user Will for spotting typos]

$\sqrt{xy}=\sqrt x\sqrt y$

$ax^2+bx+c=a\left(x-{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}\over2a}\right)\left(x-{-b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}\over2a}\right)$

$a^4+b^4=(a^2-\sqrt2ab+b^2)(a^2+\sqrt2ab+b^2)$

$a^5-b^5=(a-b)\left(a^2+{1-\sqrt5\over2}ab+b^2\right)\left(a^2+{1+\sqrt5\over2}ab+b^2\right)$

Here are some more, from G. Chrystal, Textbook of Algebra:

$\sqrt{{x+y\over x-y}}+\sqrt{{x-y\over x+y}}={2x\over\sqrt{x^2-y^2}}$

$\sqrt{{a+\sqrt{a^2-b}\over2}}+\sqrt{{a-\sqrt{a^2-b}\over2}}=\sqrt{a+\sqrt b}$

$\left({1+\sqrt{1-x}\over1-\sqrt{1-x}}\right)^{1/2}+\left({1-\sqrt{1-x}\over1+\sqrt{1-x}}\right)^{3/2}={2(2-x)\over x^2}(\sqrt x-\sqrt{x-x^2})$

$\bigl(\sqrt{p^2+1}+\sqrt{p^2-1}\bigr)^{-3}+\bigl(\sqrt{p^2+1}-\sqrt{p^2-1}\bigr)^{-3}=(p^2-(1/2))\sqrt{p^2+1}$

$\sqrt{\sqrt{a^2+\root3\of{a^4b^2}}+\sqrt{b^2+\root3\of{a^2b^4}}}=(a^{2/3}+b^{2/3})^{3/4}$

Answer (score 17):

$$\sqrt{1+\sqrt{N}} + \sqrt{N+N\sqrt{N}} - \sqrt{3N+1+(N+3)\sqrt{N}} \ = 0$$

---

$$\sqrt{ (\sin{\theta}+\csc{\theta})^2 +
         (\cos{\theta}+\sec{\theta})^2 -
         (\tan{\theta}-\cot{\theta})^2 } \ = 3$$

**Background of the above trigonometric identity:**

In the 1896 (but not 1893) version of S. L. Loney’s classic book **Plane Trigonometry**, I found the following amazing question on page 25:

> Prove the following statement.
>
> $$ (\sin   \alpha + \csc   \alpha)^2 + 
>     (\cos   \alpha + \sec   \alpha)^2 = 
>      \tan^2 \alpha + \cot^2 \alpha + 7 $$

I was so amazed by the $7$.  Having such a ‘large’ number in a trigonometric identity is rare.

I managed to make a cool variant of the question with an even larger number:

Simplify:

$  (\sin{\theta}+\csc{\theta})^2 +
   (\cos{\theta}+\sec{\theta})^2 -
   (\tan{\theta}-\cot{\theta})^2 $

Answer: $9$

Comment: The first identity, $\sqrt{3N+1+(N+3)\sqrt{N}}=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{N}}+\sqrt{N+N\sqrt{N}}$ can be unraveled with $(1+M)^{3/2}=\sqrt{1+3M+3M^2+M^3}$ or $=\sqrt{1+M}+M\sqrt{1+M}$, ie, expand a fractional power $x^{a/b}$ as a binomial under a root, $(x^a)^{1/b}$, or as a product with the power's integer part, $x^q\cdot x^r$. Then set $M=\sqrt{N}$ and rearrange.

Answer (score 5):

**1. Golden ratio: $\phi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$** look at the sequences [A001622](https://oeis.org/A001622) , [A139339](https://oeis.org/A139339)

$$ \sqrt{1 + 2 I} = \sqrt{\phi}+ \frac{I}{\sqrt{\phi}}$$

**2. Seven $\pi$:**
$$  7\pi  = {2^{2^2} \tan ^{-1}\left(1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2 \left(2+\sqrt{2}\right)}\right)}$$

**3. Cotangent Radicals:**

## $$\cot \frac{\pi}{2^{2^{2^2}}} = $$

$$
\sqrt{\frac{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Half-angle formulas
$$
\sin \frac{\theta}{2} = \pm \sqrt{\frac{1-\cos\theta}{2}}
\\
\cos \frac{\theta}{2} = \pm \sqrt{\frac{1+\cos\theta}{2}}
\\
\tan \frac{\theta}{2} = \pm \sqrt{ \frac{1-\cos\theta}{1+\cos\theta}}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $x$ be any real number greater than $1$ so that both of the following iterated square roots converge:

$a=\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+...}}}$

$b=\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x-...}}}$

Then

$a^2-b^2=(x+a)-(x-b)=a+b$

and therefore

$a-b=\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+...}}}-\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x-...}}}=1.$

Answer (score 3):

Just a sample,

$$\sqrt[3]{\frac1{9}}+\sqrt[3]{-\frac2{9}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac4{9}}=\left(4\sqrt[3]{\frac2{3}}-5\sqrt[3]{\frac1{3}}\right)^{1/8}$$

$$\sqrt[5]{\frac1{25}}+\sqrt[5]{\frac3{25}}+\sqrt[5]{-\frac9{25}}=\left(\sqrt[5]{\frac{32}{5}}-\sqrt[5]{\frac{27}{5}}\right)^{1/3}$$

$$\sqrt[5]{-\frac1{125}}+\sqrt[5]{\frac2{125}}+\sqrt[5]{\frac8{125}}+\sqrt[5]{\frac{16}{125}}=\left(\sqrt[5]{\frac1{5}}+\sqrt[5]{\frac4{5}}\right)^{1/2}$$

and a lot more by **Ramanujan**. These are just special cases of more *general* identities.

When it comes to unusual radicals, there was none more prolific than him. Just google "Ramanujan and radicals", and it should keep you busy for a while. Try:

"*Ramanujan's Association with Radicals in India*" (by Berndt, et al)

"*[Radicals and units in Ramanujan's work](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa87/aa8725.pdf)*" (by Berndt, et al)