# How do I simplify $\sqrt{\frac{1-\frac{\sqrt5 }5}2}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, nested-radicals

I've been stuck on simplifying this nested radical. I've included a snapshot of the problem and solution that is in the trigonometry book that I am studying.

I've omitted the actual trig problem and just posted a pic of the part that is stumping me. I get the first part correctly but the second part of the equation (the actual correct answer according to the book) is what is stumping me.

I don't know if the book is wrong but any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: $\dfrac{\sqrt{50-10\sqrt5}}{10}=\sqrt{\dfrac{50-10\sqrt5}{100}}=\sqrt{\dfrac{1-\dfrac{\sqrt5 }5}2}$

Comment: What is your question? The one in the title seems different from the [linked nested radical](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOFuz.jpg).

Comment: It's the one in the pic. I'll try to edit the plain text in the question to reflect the equation in the pic.

Comment: The pic has $\color{red}{\dfrac{}5}$, which your title does not

Comment: Thanks. I tried to edit it but someone beat me to it.

Comment: $\sqrt{\frac{1 - \frac{a}{a^2}}{2}}$ = $\sqrt{\frac{a^2 - a}{2a^2}}$ ??  = $\sqrt{\frac{a - 1}{2a}}$. As $a \to \infty$, the expression tends to $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} = 0.7071...$ (extra).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work from the inside outward. Start by simplifying the fractions in the radical:
$$
\sqrt{\dfrac{1-\dfrac{\sqrt5 }5}2}=\sqrt{\dfrac{\dfrac 5 5 -\dfrac{\sqrt5 }5}2}=\sqrt{\dfrac {5 -\sqrt5 }{10}}
$$
Then, you can remove the radical from the denominator:
$$
\sqrt{\dfrac {5 -\sqrt5 }{10}}=\dfrac{ \sqrt{5 -\sqrt 5 }}{\sqrt{10}}=\dfrac {\sqrt{10}}{\sqrt{10}}\dfrac{ \sqrt{5 -\sqrt 5 }}{\sqrt{10}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{10} \sqrt{5 -\sqrt 5 }}{10}
$$
Finally, combine the radicals in the numerator:
$$
\dfrac{ \sqrt{50 -10\sqrt 5 }}{10}
$$

Comment: +1. I would do the same.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, Alex. I think I added an extra nest or something making it both incorrect and more complicated. Or I skipped a step. Breaking it down into more steps illustrates the problem and answer well.

Answer (score 0):

I find it easier to go backwards:  $\dfrac{\sqrt{50-10\sqrt5}}{10}=\sqrt{\dfrac{50-10\sqrt5}{100}}=\sqrt{\dfrac{1-\dfrac{\sqrt5 }5}2}.$

This equality does not involve denesting radicals, but for those see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/196155/strategies-to-denest-nested-radicals-sqrtab-sqrtc).

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt{\frac{1-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{5}}{2}} = \sqrt{\frac{(1-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{5})\cdot 50}{2 \cdot 50}} = \sqrt{\frac{50-10\sqrt{5}}{100}} = \frac{\sqrt{50-10\sqrt{5}}}{10}$$

Comment: it looks like I just did the opposite of Mr. Tanner did... but yeah

Answer (score 0):

$\sqrt {\frac{\frac{\sqrt 5}{\sqrt 5} - \frac{1}{\sqrt 5}}{2}} = \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt 5 - 1}{2 \sqrt 5}} = \sqrt{\frac{\Phi}{\sqrt 5} - \frac{1}{{\sqrt5}}} = \sqrt {\frac{\Phi - 1}{\sqrt 5}}$

Can you please post the problem.