# Denest $\sqrt{5^{\frac{1}{3}}-4^{\frac{1}{3}}}$

Tags: nested-radicals

I'd like to ask how to denest the nested radical $\sqrt{5^{\frac{1}{3}}-4^{\frac{1}{3}}}$?

Comment: what makes you think it can be denested?

Comment: It seems that Ramanujan has got the answer $\frac{1}{3}(-25^\frac{1}{3}+20^\frac{1}{3}+2^\frac{1}{3})$. My following question is how to check whether $\sqrt{p^\frac{1}{3}-q^\frac{1}{3}}$ could be denested.

Comment: see this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194030/simplify-sqrt-sqrt35-sqrt34?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Hang Wu, see this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3492510/find-the-positive-integers-a-b-and-c-s-t-sqrt-sqrt35-sqrt34/3493069#3493069) for a general identity for such radicals.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks for your link.