# Number Theory Equality of Radicals

Tags: arithmetic, radicals

Suppose I have an equality $9\sqrt{5} = \sqrt{26} + \sqrt{3}$ (I know this is a false equation, but bear with me).
Does the fact that these do not simplify to 0 = 0 imply that these two expressions are not equal? I know you could simply approximate the square roots, but I wanted a quick rule to determine equality. To me it seems like they wouldn't be equal, intuitively. Can someone please give me a rule for this that is supported by (I'm assuming) basic number theory and explain the property? Thank you.

Comment: You could talk about $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{13})$ and how $\sqrt{5}$ is not an element of this if you wanted to go about this with algebra.

Comment: Please provide some context, e.g. do you know any abstract algebra such as field theory and linear algebra?

Comment: No, I don't. The problem actually originated from finding colinearity in R^3 in my Multivariable text and made me wonder about this.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a "quick" rule for such problems *in general*, since radicals encompass a wide range of types of numbers.  Consider this *nested* radical equality, which I found with a web search:
$$
\sqrt{5} + \sqrt{22+2\sqrt{5}} = \sqrt{11+2\sqrt{29}} + \sqrt{16 - 2\sqrt{29} + 2\sqrt{55-10\sqrt{29}}}.
$$
An approach to such problems other than feeding it into a computer will probably have to account for idiosyncratic properties of the particular numbers involved.

Comment: There are in fact poly-time algorithms for certain classes, e.g. see [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4697/242)

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can use  : $$ 2 < \sqrt{5} < 3 \implies  18 < 9\sqrt{5} < 27 $$

$$\ 5 < \sqrt{26} <6,  \ 1<\sqrt{3}<2 \implies 6<\sqrt{26}+ \sqrt{3}<8$$

to see they aren't equal, in general this is a simple check to use, however you can easily see it could fail.

Comment: "I know you could simply approximate the square roots, but I wanted a quick rule to determine equality."

Comment: you're right, but I didn't get if my answer was what the OP meant. Anyway I upvoted your answer because I think it's superior :)