# When is $\sqrt{n-\sqrt{m}}=\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}$ where $m,n\in\Bbb{Z}^+$ and $a,b\in\Bbb{Q}$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, radicals

In this youtube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aLEIYrgqEI0), Pratik Matematik asked "$\sqrt{\sqrt{49}-\sqrt{48}}=?$".

I generalized it as $\sqrt{n-\sqrt{n^2-k^2}}=\sqrt{\frac{n+k}{2}}-\sqrt{\frac{n-k}{2}}$.

And the solution of PM's question is $\sqrt{\frac{7+1}{2}}-\sqrt{\frac{7-1}{2}}=2-\sqrt{3}.$

Can you give another family of examples where $m$ is not in the form $n^2-k^2$ and still $\sqrt{n-\sqrt{m}}=\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}$ where $n,m$ are positive integers and $a,b\in\Bbb{Q}$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Squaring both sides gives $n=a+b, m=4ab.$ But $4ab=n^2-(a-b)^2.$ So if $k=a-b,$ it seems like you will get your general case.

Comment: So the general cases will probably be cases where $\sqrt m$ is rational, which are not interesting, but certainly can be made an infinite family.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews So the question is not interesting?

Comment: Well, the question is interesting, but the answer is that there are no interesting examples.

Comment: Your generalization is a special case of the general formula I give [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/816527/242) in the linked dupe (which always works when a denesting exists). In the proof there we have $\,s = n+k-\sqrt{n^2-k^2},\,$ and $\,t = \sqrt{2(n+k)},\,$ and the result $\,s/t\,$ yields your formula.

Comment: More generally see the [Radical Denesting Structure Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4697/242) and the citations there for general theory.